# How to have one JPanel show up and the second one disappear on button click?

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener

So I have 3 separate classes, the settings button on the mainmenu class should switch to main menu, but it simply hides the first panel, same thing when i click return on the other menu, i would like to find a simple soluton without using a layout manager because i don't know how to have card layout communicate to the 2 classes, but thats the solution, it'd be nice if someone could give me some pointers on how to implement that:

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    MainMenu mainMenu;
    Settings settings;

    public Game(){
        setSize(900,900);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        settings = new Settings();

        mainMenu.setSettings(settings);
        settings.setMainMenu(mainMenu);

        add(settings,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(mainMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel {
    Settings settings;

    public void setSettings(Settings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public MainMenu() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        JButton Newgame = new JButton("New Game");
        JButton Cont = new JButton("Continue");
        JButton Sett = new JButton("Settings");
        add(Newgame);
        add(Cont);
        SwitchMenu1 switchMenu1 = new SwitchMenu1();
        Sett.addActionListener(switchMenu1);
        add(Sett);
    }



    class SwitchMenu1 implements ActionListener{
        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(isVisible()){
                settings.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);

            }

        }
    }


}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Settings extends JPanel {
    MainMenu mainMenu;

    public void setMainMenu(MainMenu mainMenu) {
        this.mainMenu = mainMenu;
    }

    public Settings(){
        JButton Return = new JButton("Return");
        SwitchMenu2 switchMenu2 = new SwitchMenu2();
        Return.addActionListener(switchMenu2);
        add(Return, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    class SwitchMenu2 implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(isVisible()){
                mainMenu.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to  have the other JPanel show up on button click, but it doesn't work, the first one simply disappears. How can i fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The simple answer is to use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778844/how-to-have-the-program-regenerate-a-new-game-where-previous-grid-letters-get) by another user has a lot in common with this one ?

Comment: I wonder why the code was removed from the question. Is it related to my previous comment ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a use case for [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). You have a JPanel, named for example `cards`, which uses a CardLayout manager. You add all your panels (cards) to that panel, giving them unique names (e.g., "MAIN_MENU", "SETTINGS", etc.). Then, instead of passing every other panel in each of your panels, you only pass the cards panel, which can be used to show the card you wish, e.g., `cl.show(cards, "SETTINGS");` on clicking a button, for instance.

### Update

As per @c0der's suggestion (see comments section below), the code structure has been updated.

**Game.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    JPanel cards;
    CardLayout cardLayout;
    
    public Game(){
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        cards.add(mainMenu, "MAIN_MENU");
        cards.add(settings, "SETTINGS");
        mainMenu.setSetBtnActionListener(new BtnController("SETTINGS"));
        settings.setReturnBtnActionListener(new BtnController("MAIN_MENU"));
        add(cards);
        setSize(640,480);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class BtnController implements ActionListener {
        String cardName;
        public BtnController(String cardName) {
            this.cardName = cardName;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(cards, cardName);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

**MainMenu.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel {
    JButton setBtn;
    
    public MainMenu() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        JButton newGameBtn = new JButton("New Game");
        JButton contBtn = new JButton("Continue");
        setBtn = new JButton("Settings");
        add(newGameBtn);
        add(contBtn);
        add(setBtn);
    }

    public void setSetBtnActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        setBtn.addActionListener(al);
    }
}
```

**Settings.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Settings extends JPanel {
    JButton returnBtn;
    
    public Settings() {
        returnBtn = new JButton("Return");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(returnBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void setReturnBtnActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        returnBtn.addActionListener(al);
    }
}
```

Comment: ` CardLayout` is indeed the right tool. I would suggest changing the structure to avoid coupling between `Settings` and `MainMenu`.  One simple way to do it is to use  `public void setActionListene(ActionListene al) { returnBtn.addActionListener(al); }` instead of `setCards`

Comment: Final touchup: remove `Settings settings;` from `MainMenu` and `MainMenu` reference from `Settings`